# Accuracy of data type float (IEEE 754 Single-precision)

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

I found on the Wikipedia page for IEEE 754 a diagram that shows the relationship between floating point precision and the actual floating point value (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Formats):

[image]

Is it correct to interpret this diagram so, that smaller values are generally "more accurate" than bigger values?

In my concrete case, I have an application that counts mass flow (in range of 0-90 grams/s) into a float accumulator/totalizer. I thought it would be better, in respect to the precision diagram, I mentioned first, to use a "bigger unit" for the totalizer itself, so that the actual float value is always at a lower range: this means in my case using tons instead of grams for the totalizer unit.

Is that consideration correct or would be there no benefit for using a float totalizer who counts in grams or tons?

Comment: There is one way to manipulate floating-point numbers for greater relative precision, and that is to arrange for the significands to be higher. E.g., for numbers in [1, 2), the unit of least precision (ULP, the smallest change that can be made in a floating-point number because it is the distance between adjacent representable numbers) is 2^−23 for IEEE-754 binary32 numbers. So for numbers around 1.1, the relative error is 2^−23/1.1, approximately 1.084e−7. If we scale the measuring unit so the numbers are instead around 1.9, the relative error is 2^−23/1.9, approximately 0.627e−7…

Comment: … However, this is impractical for most uses of floating-point arithmetic. Common uses involve performing various operations in which the significands are unpredictable in practice. It might be occasionally useful in special-purpose code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct interpretation of the diagram is that precision is relative to magnitude.

Let's say that your number is around 100 (because you're measuring in grams). That means that your precision is around 1e-5 grams (That's about the mass of a small grain of sand.)

Now let's say that you instead measure in units of MASS OF THE SUN. Now your number is 5e-32 solar masses. The relative precision is now around 5e-37 solar masses. That's about the mass of a small grain of sand.

So no, no benefit. The point of floating point numbers is to keep you from having to worry about magnitude.

If you're worried about the overall accuracy of summing many numbers, use [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Comment: Your words make sense, thank you very much for your explanation! I think my problem was that I assumed, that the precision is not constant and changes over the range, but since the diagram only shows two straight lines, this consideration was just wrong...